# spring.profiles.active placeholder resolve problem

Tags: spring-boot

```
info:
  app:
    env-active: dev
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${info.app.env-active}
```

In my case, I want to use placeholder for setting spring.profiles.active. in my springboot application (application.yml), but when I start the project, the log is showing like blow.

`The following profiles are active: dev,${info.app.env-active}`

The real property is truly resolved, but the placeholder is still exists. Is that an bugs?

Comment: `dev` in your active profiles comes from somewhere else I think, your placeholder is not resolved.

Comment: this time I use env replace env-active  and the log is The following profiles are active: dev,${info.app.env}.

Comment: How about trying to resolve that property within your spring environment? Can you try to check by trying to bind it to a value with `@Value("${info.app.env-active}")` ? If that works, that means you somehow get issue when resolving placeholder within same yml file...

Comment: 'dev' in my case only can come for here,  cause i just set this property for validate the problem.

Comment: It is not possible to have it resolved & not resolved at the same time... Can you check whether you have `spring.profiles.include` configuration with a value `dev` anywhere. That property does not override but adds new profile to the existing active set of profiles.

Comment: i believe `info.app.env-active` can be resolved because in my springboot-admin project, i can see this property in page.

Comment: You need to add more details, is there any other place where you modify profiles? I have no explanation on how you get both key & value in such a manner.

Comment: when i debug the starting of springboot application. i find the framework first find `spring.profiles.active`, but in this moment, the environment doesn't contain `info.app.env-active` property. so the put the placeholder into environment.  after a few moment, when `info.app.env-active` resolved and put into enironment, the `spring.profles.active` can be resolved in real value (dev) , so they put env into environment (cause `${info.app.env-active}` not eq `dev`, think two profile...).

Comment: hmm I see, but why the value would be fetched twice, that is confusing... Maybe due to the changing value of `spring.profiles.active` it triggers reevaluation after the placeholder is resolved? But why it does not override, but appends to the existing profile? I never encountered this case, pretty crazy lol